# Visibility of elements in CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I'm writing a React app, but my question I'm thinking is not about React but about CSS. I have a bar from which the user can choose a sort option:

```
    <div className="innerLineVisor">
        <div className="sortLine" ref={lineRef}>
            {cuisines.map(cuisine =>
                <div key={cuisine.id} className="sortButton">{cuisine.value}</div>
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here are their styles:

```
.innerLineVisor {
    width: 80%;
    height: 40px;
    border: #C80303 1px solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
}

.sortLine {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: inline;
    transition: 1s;
}

.sortButton {
    float: left;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border: darkgray 1px solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now when one of the buttons does not fit on the left, I can see part of it. And on the right is empty until the button fits completely.

[image]

What can I do to see part of the button on the right as well?

This is the arrow code:

```
function leftMotion() {
    setLimitPositions({...limitPositions, right: false})

    if (linePosition + step > 0) {
        lineRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'left: 0')
        setLinePosition(0)
        setLimitPositions({...limitPositions, left: true})
        return
    }

    lineRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'left:' + (linePosition + step) + 'px')
    setLinePosition(linePosition + step)

    if (limitPositions.left && arrowsPressed.left) {
        lineRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'left:' + (linePosition + 10) + 'px')
    }
}

function rightMotion() {
    setLimitPositions({...limitPositions, left: false})

    lineRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'left:' + (linePosition - step) + 'px')
    setLinePosition(linePosition - step)

    const lineVisorWidth = getLineVisorWidth()
    if (lineVisorWidth > (lineLength - (Math.abs(linePosition))) - lineVisorWidth) {
        const limitRightPosition = lineLength - lineVisorWidth
        lineRef.current.setAttribute('style', 'left:' + (-limitRightPosition) + 'px')
        setLinePosition(-limitRightPosition)
        setLimitPositions({...limitPositions, right: true})
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using flex on the parent instead of all those floats? And what do those arrows do to move the list along?

Comment: Thanks, flex really helped. And the arrows are needed in order to move the line with options.

Comment: Yes, I understand why the arrows are needed, but my question was what do they do - what is the code?

Comment: I've added the arrow code if you're still interested.